# Aptitude - Both 64 & 32-bit packages being selected

Tags: 64-bit, package-management, 14.04, aptitude

In aptitude, I selected the xubuntu-desktop task and was presented with a large number of package conflicts, per this example:

[image]

It seems that both the 32- and 64-bit versions of packages are being selected and the resolver doesn't seem to know what to do about it.

I can manually de-select the i386 version of each of the conflicting packages but that will be a lengthy task.

Is there a way to do one or both of the following?

1. bulk-deselect the 32-bit versions wherever a 64-bit version has also been selected ?
2. prevent this situation in the first place ?

## Update 1

per @Luis Alvarado's suggestion below, I ran `aptitude install xubuntu-desktop` direct from the command line and it seems to have not hit any conflicts - so my immediate issues have been resolved.

Still, I'll leave this question open for now as I'm interested as to why I'm encountering this behaviour in the curses ui.

## Update 2

Even with using the command line rather than the ncurses gui I now have a problem where the updates for all the stuff that had been selected in the gui won't apply because of the conflict between the 32-bit and 64-bit packages.

Eeek.

How do I get around this without manually resolving the conflicts 1 at a time ?

Comment: Did you try doing it in the terminal and not on the curse gui: aptitude install xubuntu-desktop?

Comment: @LuisAlvarado, no but on your suggestion I've done that and it worked.  Have updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: why not apt-get? why aptitude, aptitude is for debian

Comment: aptitude is much better than apt-get in solving dependency issues, broken packages and cleaning correctly. Still on 14.04 I would go with aptitude. Additionally with aptitude you can do everything with one single command (aptitude), with apt-get you still can not.

Comment: If you attempt "Manual package selection" using the [Ubuntu mini (64bit) install ISO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) you are **forced** to use _aptitude_ and will be promptly met with such a nightmare described above. (See [this SO question for reference](http://superuser.com/questions/645338/dependency-problems-due-to-conflicts-when-installing-ubuntu-mini)). Obviously this is Canonical's way of saying people who want a minimal install via `mini.iso` are freaks and should feel bad about themselves.